# date getValue() is one day off from getDisplayValue()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell that's date formatted and set to: "Sat, Nov 2, 2019".

But when I look up that cells date with a script, it's one day off (-1).

```
var date = new Date();
date = sheet_log.getRange(110, 1).getValue();
var dateDisplay = sheet_log.getRange(110, 1).getDisplayValue();
// date = Fri Nov 01 2019 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
// dateDisplay = Sat, Nov 2, 2019
```

Why would Google Sheets let me set a date using a calendar picker, yet compute a date minus one day in script?

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

Although I'm not sure about your actual condition, for example, the values of the timezone for the spreadsheet and the timezone for the script are different, such situation might occur.

- The value retrieved by `getValue()` follows the timezone of the script.
- The value retrieved by `getDisplayValue()` follows the timezone of the Spreadsheet.

The both timezones can be confirmed by the following script.

```
var timezone1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var timezone2 = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
Logger.log(timezone1)
Logger.log(timezone2)
```

- If `timezone1` is different from `timezone2`, it is considered that the reason of the issue is due to the different timezone. In this case, please set the timezone of Spreadsheet or script.
- If `timezone1` is the same with `timezone2`, it is considered that the reason of the issue is not due to the timezone. So it is required to investigate more for clarifying the reason of issue.

#### References:

- [getSpreadsheetTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetTimeZone())
- [getScriptTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getScriptTimeZone())

If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Your suggestion helped. It turns out that my spreadsheet has a similar but different time zone (timezone1 = America/Chicago, timezone2 = America/Mexico_City). The Google Script editor preferences has it's own timezone settings that were different.

Comment: @Adam Glazier Thank you for replying. I could know that my guess was correct for your situation. If you want the same results between Spreadsheet and script, please use the same timezone. But if my answer didn't resolve your issue, I have to apologize.